# Adding knockout to a controller/view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout-mvc

MVC/C#/Knockout

I'm learning knockout right now and trying different things.

Up to this point I was doing knockout in the html code but I found [this example](http://knockoutmvc.com/Region) to play with.

The namespace line in the view

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
```

is not found.

So I followed the [quickstart](http://knockoutmvc.com/Home/QuickStart) out to ensure I was setting things up right.

The lines:

```
@{
 var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
```

CreateKnockoutContext() is not a selectable item in the list.

Also, in the controller:

```
    public class TestController : KnockoutController
```

is not a valid name space.  I can't add knockout as a namespace as a

using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;

since it's not there...  I don't see it as a reference after I added it from nuget and I can't find it to add it as a reference either...

My bundle config contains this:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"));
```

And I have knockout added to the project.  I can use knockout in the HTML but I'd like to play with code like this:

```
@using (ko.If(model => model.Condition2))
{
  <p>Condition2</p>
}
```

Comment: Ah, I believe part of my problem is I have the nuget package "knockout" installed but did not have the kMVC nuget installed.  Do I need both or should I remove the knockout and leave kMVC?  (I still can't add the @using in the view yet though... looking at my bundles)

Comment: Sure, I fight this for a couple of hours and figure it out shortly after posting...  The answer is that I needed to add the kMVC nuget package to the project (still not sure if I need both kMVC and knockout packages?) Then I had to add perpetuum.knockout to my bundles config.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing PerpetuumSoft.Knockout from the server side, and need to install the nuget package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/kMVC, and then make sure you have the "using" reference on the page you are using the code in.

Comment: That was absolutely not the case. I had the library included and it was resolved (as listed in my original question).